# How to get clicked img src and pass it to the next view function

Tags: html, flask

I am using flask to deploy my model for image similarity search. To run it, I will have two pages:

1) first page (say, query.html) that shows a randomly generated image from my dataset; users can continue to refresh this page till they see an item that they like. In html, it would be something like `<img src="{{ random_path }}" alt="">`. When the user is satisfied, the image needs to be clicked to direct to the next page;

2) second page (say, results.html) that takes the img src from the first page, and run the model at backend and return the similar images.

I am now confused how I should link step 1) to step 2) - how to get the img src on click and pass that information on to the next step?

Comment: seems related to html and javascript as getting image link on click and pass it to another page component has nothing to do with python

Comment: use `<a href="...">` which has `href` with information about image - it can be its url, or its unique name or its ID in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a form with hidden input tags and make a post request (More on flask's post request [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#the-request-object)) to pass on the data from one page to the other. In code it would look something like this:

**HTML:**

```
 <html>
   <body>
      <form action = "/imagematch" method = "post">
         <p><input type = "hidden" name = "imagesrc" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Python Backend:**

```
@app.route('/imagematch',methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      user = request.form.get('imagesrc')
```

Alternatively you can use JavaScript localstorage/sessionStorage. More on localstorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

Comment: Thanks very much! Hidden input did the trick for me. I edited a bit on the html script so I can submit the image as input: <p><input type = "hidden" name = "imagesrc" value = {{ "url_path" }} /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" src = {{ "url_path" }}/></p

Comment: Great! . Feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others as well!

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a `<form>` and place the `<input type="hidden">` (with base64 format of the image as value) or `<input type="hidden">` (with the server file path as value) whichever comfortable and upon submitting the form the image path/base64 format of the image as value will be sent to server.
   Or
2. Using Javascript or JQuery upon user selects the image, send the image to the server via a AJAX request and do whatever you want at the server-side and return the status to the user accordingly.

Option 1 is simple and straight forward and you need to deal with base64 conversion.

Option 2 is a little complex and needs good JQuery expertise.

Comment: Add a querystring to the href that directs to the second page with the model to use.

Comment: @DovRine yeah works flawlessly, if it is a path to the image is sent in the query parameter and unsafe tho, also if it is a base64 string.